# Perl String Compare fails

Tags: string, perl, compare

Below is the sample of the code:

```
while (@filelines){
  #splice the line to a array 
  print "the string to be compared is $filelines[$i] with $FN_Accessories_Header\n";

  if (chomp($filelines[$i]) eq $FN_Accessories_Header){
    print "The file name is FN_Accessories.csv and first line is header\n";
  }
  else {
    print "The scanning process will be terminated as the first line is not header\n";
    exit;
  }
}
```

The contents of the two variables is the same, but the print in if statement does not execute.

`asd_bsd;asdf_asdf;weroi_asdf;asdf_asdf;asdf_wer;rty_tyu;sdf_erty;qwe_123;asdffff_asdfrs;`

Comment: Where is `$i` coming from?

Comment: Also: Where's `@filelines` coming from. And what are you `chomp`ing for?

Comment: $i is a temp var i initialized to 0 for count. @filelines is coming from reading the file.

Comment: i thought it may have \n or new line at the end so i chomped it.

Comment: @Riss: You need to `chomp()` i **before** doing the comparison. `chomp($filelines[$i])` gives an integer, **not** the chomped string.

Answer (score 6):

[chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) doesn't return the shortened string, it returns the number of characters removed.

```
chomp @filelines;
for my $line (@filelines) {
    if ($line eq $FN_Accessories_Header) {
    ...
```

Comment: my $i = 0;
    chomp @filelines;
    while (@filelines)
    {
        #splice the line to a array 
        if ($filelines[$i] eq $FN_Accessories_Header)
        {
            print "The file name is FN_Accessories.csv and first line is header\n";
        }
        else
        {
            print "The scanning process will be terminated as the first line is not header\n";
            exit;
        }
    }

Comment: Its still going on the else path.

Comment: Where do you change `$i`? `while (@filelines)` runs the loop until the array is empty, where do you remove elements from the array?

Comment: @resalathahamed: Please don't dump code in comments like that. Much better to edit your question to add the new version of the code.

Comment: @DaveCross: Sure, I will remember that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

- `while (@filelines)` will always be true unless you remove elements from `@filelines` in the loop (which you don't).
- You don't  do anything to change `$i` in the loop, so `$filelines[$i]` will always be the same string. That's probably not what you want.
- `chomp()` returns a boolean value (whether or not a newline was removed from the string). So comparing its return value to another string is unlikely to be useful. **Update:** choroba points out (correctly) in a comment that `chomp()` returns a more useful value that can be interpreted as a boolean in many cases. See the [documentation for `chomp()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) for more details.

Some combination of these three errors is causing your problem.

Comment: chomp returns the number of characters removed from all its parameters, but you can interpret it as a boolean in Perl :-)

Comment: Hi, I understood my mistakes in the code, however, the focus of the issue was still to check what exactly went wrong with the "eq". Eventually I figured that even after executing chomp(), i was unable to succeed in the compare, So, as a temp work around, i have used length to determine if its the header of the csv or not (as its not bound to change). This succeeds with a workaround.

Comment: @Riss: Nothing went wrong with the `eq`. The `eq` did exactly what it was supposed to do. You compare the return value from `chomp()` (which is an integer - probably 1) with your string (which is not an integer). That is always going to fail.

Answer (score 1):

try perl debug, the commands below should get you there. then you can compare both strings live to see what's up

```
perl -d ./yourscript
b <LINENUMBER>
L
c
print "--".$filelines[$i]."--"
print "--".$FN_Accessories_Header."--"
```

Key for above b "breakpoint" , L "list breakpoints" , c "continue to breakpoint", print "print"